# SQL Join and contains

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Transactions 
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT ID FROM Customers 
                     WHERE Name LIKE '%Test%')
```

It takes 10 seconds to run, however if I create the query manually by taking the 4 values returned by the sub query it runs in milliseconds, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Transactions 
WHERE (CustomerID = 1 OR CustomerID = 2 OR
       CustomerID = 3 OR CustomerID = 4)
```

To clarify, running

```
SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE Name LIKE '%Test%'
```

returns the values 1,2,3,4 immediately

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: Your next troubleshooting step should be to look at the `execution plan`. You could do this straight through SQL, or you could use SSMS. Off hand, you could check to make sure the CustomerID and ID columns are the same datatypes, just in case an index on Transactions is being ignored (I assume there is an index, since it returns immediately when you specify the values). You could also try turning this into a join instead of a sub query. Eg `select t.* from Transactions t join Customers c on (t.CustomerID=c.ID) where c.Name like '%Test%'`, but it's unlikely to have an impact.

Comment: Thanks, join produces the exact same 10 second execution time, both fields are type uniqueidentifier. Any other ideas, really a strange issue.

Comment: Show us the actual execution plan. You can use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already said, when you have the customer id's it runs in milliseconds so the filtering of the customer name is the problem.

The first wildcard (WHERE name LIKE '%Test%') is the suspect here because sql server needs to read all the strings in the name column like a regular expression and find if there is any "Test" in there for every row in the table!

If the names you are filtering for would always start with a "Test" and you could do a WHERE name LIKE 'Test%' it would work much better because sql server only needs to read the start of each string.

Edit:

Here is a little bit different version of the original query if you want to try:

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM 
    Customers c
    WHERE c.ID = t.CustomerID 
    AND c.Name LIKE '%Test%'
)
```

Comment: No, the query of the "sub" table runs in milliseconds as well. Even with a SQL join the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

What happens with a `join`?

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Transactions t JOIN
     Customers c
     ON t.CustomerID = c.ID
WHERE c.Name Like '%Test%';
```

Sometimes, `JOIN`s optimize better than `IN`.

Comment: Same problem, the table has around 20 million records, we currently have a join which is the main issue.